# How to remove the style attribute from li tag nested within two divs via Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to remove the style attributes from the li tags.

```
<div class="hello mr person">
<div class="garage">
<ul class="stuff">
<li style="width: 148px;"></li>
<li style="width: 148px;"></li>
<li style="width: 148px;"></li>
<li style="width: 148px;"></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

for some reason the following won't work, i know i'm close but I don't see what I did wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".hello.mr.person").find(".garage").find(".stuff li style").remove();
   });
</script>
```

Comment: You forgot to close your li tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply you can do

```
$("li").removeAttr("style"); //removes all  li style attributes.
```

If `li` in a div

```
  $('.garage li').removeAttr("style"); // remove specifically inside a div.
```

Comment: you wouldn't happen to know how to make sure we're targeting the top and 2nd div?

Comment: you can use css3 style :nth-child / :nth-of-type jQuery selectors for that

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
$('div div li').removeAttr('style');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$(".stuff li").removeAttr("style"); // Remove all li styles within .stuff ul
```

If you use

```
$("li")..
```

you will remove the style for all `<li>` elements on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this way.

```
$("li").attr('style','');
```